# Difference between angled brackets and parentheses in HLSL texture samplers

Tags: directx, direct3d, hlsl

Is there any important difference between using parentheses and angled brackets for texture sampler parameters? I have used them interchangeably before without any different effect.

For instance

```
Sampler TexSceneSampler {
    Texture = <TexScene>;
}
```

Versus

```
Sampler TexSceneSampler {
    Texture = (TexScene);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angular brackets is the correct format according to the docs.  However, AFAIK, there are no differences between the 2.  I'd stick to the angular though in case the compiler gets changed. Mind its a DX9 only thing so you'll probably be ok either way.